Stroustrup's PPP Memory Management Stack Example

Notice this comment in the code:

space for char[N] and data to keep track of what is allocated and what is not (e.g., a top-of-stack pointer)

In my opinion, only a top-of-stack pointer isn't enough for this interface. Instead, we need to maintain a list of pointers where we allocated so we can correctly revert the last allocation when we free().
Am I wrong or is there some mistake in the book?

"... and data to keep track of what is allocates and what is not..." should cover that, I think. The "top-of-stack pointer" is just an example of the data that is needed, but the book doesn't say it's the only data needed.

@Someprogrammerdude All right, maybe I take it wrong.

You don't need a separate list of pointers. It's not uncommon to store the previous value of top-of-stack pointer as a part of every allocated chunk (stack frame). Low-level CPU execution stack does this.

It's a nitpick, but I wish Stroustrup had said: // return nullptr if no space.

@tbxfreeware I think the whole example is really outdated and C++ shouldn't be used like this anymore.   This kind of allocation should be a hidden part of ANY class (and the void* should not leak out of a Stack class). In fact that's why the STL library has "Allocator"'s as an extra template argument.

You need to take some microprocessor courses/books. Call stack is a very common b concept in design of microprocessors. Write a simple hello world program and open the disassembly in your IDE; you should then get a grasp of how to handle the stack with a top pointer alone.

It's funny how memory usage display in Windows now looks like that image from his book.
I think that interface was meant as an example, not as a canonical implementation.
Stack is kind of structure where only location of top is changed. It's not possible to do with that implementation of stack, but technically we can implement free(int size) if we would change method of allocation and store "return" values right in stack. Normally stack structure avoids allocating for every addition, so some "return" data would be required.
What happens with "stack" (aka call stack) in programs implementation? No memory is allocated dynamically in that case. Usually (there are exceptions) OS reserves memory for program to use and program got a pointer (or register)  pointing at end of "last used" element, which would bottom of stack. Save value and increment this pointer and we had "allocated" the memory for our variable, which would have address of saved value. For optimization purposes, compiler generates code which does that in bulk.
Return addresses (pointers to stack state before function call) might be saved to a register or to stack itself. Which makes so-called tail-call possible. A function F would call function G by a jmp instruction instead of call instruction, if such call is the last action of F.
Instruction jmp unlike call doesn't save return address. If that happens, the "called" function G invokes ret instruction, which would return to the original caller instead of F, which saves some time and amount of code processed by CPU.
